# Getting VM Exception while processing transaction: revert error

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle

I am new to Blockchain. I want to call a function to read a variable from contract.
My contract

```
bool public isVoting = false;
function getIsVoting() public returns (bool) {
        return isVoting;
    }
```

At client, i call like this

```
const isVoting = async () => {
        const _isVoting = await ElectionInstance.methods
            .getIsVoting()
            .call()
            .then(console.log);
    };
```

then i got the error but did not know why :

```
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0xdbe5e039374fdc83fe873f5e55d91f05ec5d19e2e3c88351130c3f3672644e08": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 130,
      "return": "0x"
    },
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/tmp/.mount_ganachnMw5dG/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n    at /tmp/.mount_ganachnMw5dG/resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:568:26",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Unlike [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call), Truffle doesn't use the `methods` keyword. The call fails because it's trying to access (non-existing) `methods` property of the contract.

You should use the method name as a property (without the parenthesis) if you want to use the chained `call()`.

You're also combining `await` and callback function `then`, which can cause some unexpected results (but not the transaction revert).

See the [docs](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/contract-abstractions#calling-getters) for more info.

Optionally, you can mark the Solidity function as `view` because it doesn't write any data to storage. This will also allow you to use it as `ElectionInstance.getIsVoting()` function without using `.call()` in Truffle.

```
function getIsVoting() public view returns (bool) { // added `view`
    return isVoting;
}
```

```
const _isVoting = await ElectionInstance
    .getIsVoting // no parenthesis
    .call();
    // no `then`
```